# BigDecimal division throwing ArithmeticException: Division by zero even when i check against it

Tags: java, talend, ternary-operator

Hey guys I'm currently working with talend and have to calculate some KPI's.

I'm getting the `ArithmeticException: Division by zero` every time now even if I follow the same schema in different calculations and they work without problems.

```
(((functions_pattern.checkIfNull(opportunities1.tatsaechlicherumsatz)) == 
BigDecimal.ZERO) || ((functions_pattern.checkIfNull(rechnung1.netto)) == 
BigDecimal.ZERO))
 ?  BigDecimal.ZERO  
 : (rechnung1.netto.divide(opportunities1.tatsaechlicherumsatz , 
    java.math.MathContext.DECIMAL32))
```

`functions_pattern.checkIfNull` sets a `null` value to zero (in this case `BigDecimal.ZERO`) I also tried various variations on this (separate `null` checking etc.)

Also since I'm working with talend I have to use ternary operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `==` to test a `BigDecimal` is a bad idea.

Even assuming that `checkIfNull` returns `Decimal.ZERO` when `null`, you still have the problem that `rechnung1.netto` could have been a zero that is `!=` `Decimal.ZERO`.

Also `equals` has the problem that both the value and the scale must be equal for two `BigDecimal` values to be considered equal.

This is the safe way to test a (non-null) `BigDecimal` value for zero:

```
 BigDecimal x = ...
 if (x.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) {
     // it is zero
 } else {
     // it is not zero
 }
```